# Creating a batch to rename a file based on a filename in parent directory

Tags: shell, variables, powershell, cmd, command

I have a directory containing a few hundred folders. Each folder has a *.iso file and a folder with the name "Disc Art". Inside of the Disc Art folder is a *.btw file that is named usually 1.btw or 01.btw. I want to be able to change the filename of the .btw to the filename of the *.iso in the parent folder and add " - Disc 01" to it. So if I have "Windflyers.iso" I will end up with "Windflyers - Disc 01.btw"

Here is what I have tried so far. I believe I am very close. For some reason I feel the SET command is failing because when I call the variable in the next line to rename the file there is no value.

```
for /D %%f in (*.*) do (    
cd "%%f"
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.iso') do set variable=%%~na
rename "Disc Art\*.btw" "%variable% - Disc 01.btw"
cd..
)
```

I have also tried this as someone suggested at my work.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /D %%f in (*.*) do (    
cd "%%f"
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.iso') do set variable=%%~na
rename "Disc Art\*.btw" "%variable% - Disc 01.btw"
cd..
) >> log.txt
endlocal
```

**THANK YOU**
I made a slight modification to the solution below. The solution by dbenham worked but if the .iso contained spaces in the filename it only gave me the first word. I was able to get the full filename using this .bat code below.

```
for /D %%f in (*.*) do (    
cd "%%f"
for /F "tokens=*" %%* in ('dir /b *.iso') do rename "Disc Art\*.btw" "%%~n* - Disc 01.btw"
cd..
) >> log.txt
```

Comment: So the `.iso` is in the parent folder of the `.btw` file?

Comment: can you simplify the question it sounds like you are trying to rename the parent folder and sub-files is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SET is working, but you cannot set a value within a code block and then access the value within the same block using `%variable%` because the entire block is expanded at parse time before anything is executed. You can get the value you want by enabling delayed expansion and using `!variable!` instead. But that is not necessary, since you don't even need the variable at all:

```
for /D %%f in (*.*) do (    
  cd "%%f"
  for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.iso') do rename "Disc Art\*.btw" "%%~na - Disc 01.btw"
  cd..
) >> log.txt
```

There is a much simpler solution

```
(for /r %%F in (*.iso) do ren "%%~dpDisc Art\*.btw" "%%~nF - Disc 01.btw")>log.txt
```

Comment: Thank you dbenham! Your solution was exactly what I was looking for. Your first code and simplified code both worked perfectly for the task it was intended for.